# Fas fa Thumbs up disappearing

Tags: css, font-awesome

I was trying to implemented the thumbs up icon but was not able to make it work. When ever I would try to add they disappear. I hope someone can help me.

my  code:

```
<br/><br/>
<br/>
<form action="{% url 'like_post' post.pk %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type='submit', name='post_id', value="{{ post.id }}", class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Like</button> 
    <br>
    {{ total_likes }} Likes
</form>
```

Thumbsup code needed:

```
<i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i>
```

Comment: where do you try adding your thumbs up icon?

Comment: underneath the post page @coder.